# List of favorites using tweet sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tweetsharp

I am having trouble implementing a function to get the list of favorite tweets for a given user using tweetsharp. Does anyone have suggestion on how i should go about doing this? Thanks!

```js
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetTwitterFavoritesList(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier, string screen_name)
        {
            try
            {
                var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token };
                TwitterService service = new TwitterService(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);
                service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
                ListFavoriteTweetsOptions options = new ListFavoriteTweetsOptions();
                options.ScreenName = screen_name;
                options.MaxId = 100;

                IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> favoritesList = service.ListFavoriteTweets(options);

                return Json(favoritesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: How about sharing what you've tried so far?

Comment: sure thing. Ill edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the access token and access secret i got from the initial authorization. So to get favorites i did not need to do a second authorization. i saved the access token and secret and just used them again in this line

```
service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the MaxId = 100. That property is used for "paging" and setting it to 100 means no tweet with an id of more than 100 will be returned. Given all current tweets are in the billions, the query won't return anything.

If you were trying to restrict the number of tweets returned, you want to use the Count property, if one exists for that method.

Comment: I changed the property from MaxId to Count and i still have null returned.

Comment: Have you checked the .Response property of the TwitterService object? It will have the http status code and the response content will have detail of the error returns by Twitter.